# Dual Booting with xp and 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot

I have working windows 7 32 bit OS in drive C and windows xp in drive D. But I am not getting the option to select xp in boot menu. Boot menu shows two options Windows 8 Consumer Preview and Windows 7. Though I have deleted Windows 8 from drive D, but it shows in the boot menu. Now I have windows xp in drive D. I have tried using EasyBCD but it doesn't detect Windows XP.
One more thing, when I installed xp in drive D, I was only able to use XP not 7, that's why I used EasyBCD to get & back. When I got 7 back, I can't find xp, please help.

Comment: try to check allthe options of System Configuaration in Adminidtritive tools of control panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try bcedit. Make sure you running command prompt with administrative privilage,  For more help on bcedit see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29

Comment: That didn't help, I can't find any useful command for BCDEdit.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would recommend super grub. download it from http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ burn it to a disk and boot from it. menu is pretty self explanatory, there is a repair option also. Or The lengthy procedure is to reinstall windows Xp in D: then repair windows 7

Answer (score 0):

[Dual-boot Repair tool](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-tool-for-windows-8.1-update.html) can help.

One-click solution - "Automatic Repair" which places latest Windows version in control of the booting (Windows 7 in this case) and fixes Windows XP boot files if necessary.